# Lehmann-Kallen form of exact propagator in momentum space in Srednicki's QFT book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, propagator

I've been reading Srednicki's QFT book and encountered a problem with his derivation of Lehmann-Kallen form of exact propagator in momentum space, to be exact, formula 13.11 and 13.12, written as:
$$\rho(s)\equiv\sum_{n}|\langle k,n|\varphi(0)|0\rangle|^2\delta(s-M^2)\tag{13.11} $$
$$\langle0|\varphi(x)\varphi(y)|0\rangle=\int \widetilde{dk}e^{ik(x-y)}+\int_{4m^2}^{\infty}ds\rho(s)\int\widetilde{dk}e^{ik(x-y)}\tag{13.12}$$
I'm wondering whether the $\rho(s)$ term (defined as ***the Spectral Density***) can be taken out of the integral of $\widetilde{dk}$, since it is also a funtion of the wave vector k.